# WebBrowser not getting captured in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am using following code to capture screen. But browser in a page is not captured.

```
WriteableBitmap w = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap(this, null); // 'this' is your current page
WriteableBitmap w2 = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap(480, 800);

// space for SysTray
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
            for (int j = 0; j < 480; j++)
            {
                w2.Pixels[i * 480 + j] = -16777216; // black #ff000000
            }
}

// actual client area
for (int i = 32; i < 728; i++)
{
            for (int j = 0; j < 480; j++)
            {
                w2.Pixels[i * 480 + j] = w.Pixels[(i - 32) * 480 + j];
            }
}

// space for AppBar
for (int i = 728; i < 800; i++)
{
            for (int j = 0; j < 480; j++)
            {
                w2.Pixels[i * 480 + j] = -16777216; // black #ff000000
            }
}

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
w2.SaveJpeg(ms, 480, 800, 0, 100);

Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibrary lib = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibrary();
ms.Position = 0;
lib.SavePicture("screenshot", ms);
```

Comment: Where does `w` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with the current Windows Phone SDK:

> WriteableBitmap currently does not capture the content of WebBrowser
>   control or MediaElement.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/a9000cc6-7b3b-4226-a769-5217707c7165/screenshot)

Comment: What else can be used to capture screen?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way of rendering the WebBrowser to an image (excepted of course by asking the user to make a screenshot - WP8 only)